# How to select constant values from Dataframe coding in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I have a dataframe df1 with fixed number of columns. I have applied an inner join with another dataframe df2.

However, while the select is written, I need to select some constant numbers which I am currently unable to.

I have read examples in scala but corresponding java isn't working.

```
df1.join(df2).filter(df1.col("a1").$eq$eq$eq(df2.col("a1")))
.select(df1.col("a1"), df1.col("a2"), df2.col("a2"), 8)
```

Suggest a way to select 8 as in above example.

I am aware of `withColumn` api as well but not sure about the implementation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work.

```
val joinedDF = df1.join(df2).filter(df1.col("a1").$eq$eq$eq(df2.col("a1")))
.select(df1.col("a1"), df1.col("a2"), df2.col("a2")).withColumn("constant", lit(8))
```

That is if you want to add an integer. If you want to add a constant string, use this after select

```
.withColumn("constantString",lit("some_string"))
```

Comment: This resulted only in "constant" value being displayed.
or I guess I need to select the earlier ones again with the constant value.

Comment: @kks This will result in all the cols you have after join and the constant value to be displayed. Not just the constant value. If you are seeing only the constant value, might be an issue with your query. Post your query here, i can help you debug it.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I found my query bugged.
@dheee

Answer (score 2):

How about using pure sql to do this task?

```
df1.registerAsTempTable("df1");
df2.registerAsTempTable("df2");

val joinedDf = hc.sql("Select df1.a1, df1.a2, df2.a2, 8 from df1 inner join df2 on df1.a1 = df2.a1");
```

Comment: I tried that and it worked too. Thanks. However, I am more concerned about solving it using dataframe classes.

Adding one constant value using the sql method will let me change my whole dataframe join which results around 72 columns. It might be tedious. Hence, the query.

Comment: You maybe correct or may not be on this. Because the sql here is ran on dataframes itself, and the dataframe classes you used in your code, will be same which are invoked here. This is just another way of using dataframe classes, with almost no difference. Now I am not sure how joins are optimized in spark dataframe, so can't comment if it will make full 72 columns intermediate table then select 5 column, or just make intermediate join table with just 5 column, ideally it shouldn't touch columns which are not part of output or condition.

Comment: Getting from above, what I did was that I selected the constant values using pure sql into another dataframe. Made sure they could be joined with already existing dataframes. 
Then retreived them using .select(). Thanks for help.